# When to use "на свете" and when to use "в мире" in their figurative sense?

Tags: словоупотребление

> **На свете** нет ничего невозможного.
>
> Любой парень **на свете** бы ...

I can't quite put my finger on why "на свете" needs to be used in the first two instances and  "в мире" in the third. How do these two figurative expressions compare?

> Если вы собираетесь на самую страшную вечеринку **в мире**, ...

Answer (score 3):

**В мире** is based on facts about the world as objective and verifiable thing. Like:

> Байкал - самое глубокое озеро в мире.
>
> Baikal is the deepest lake in the world.

**На свете** is more of a hyperbole that isn't meant to be taken literally.

> Лучший парень на свете.
>
> Best guy in the world.

Answer (score 2):

My feeling is that

**на свете** usually refers to *of all times*, *ever* and to immaterial world

**в мире** - in the world presently and in material world

But this distinction isn't hard and fast, they might overlap or depend on the context and phraseology conventions.